# Оптимизация работы с многомерными массивами PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!
Есть функция, которая возвращает 3-х мерный массив, который содержит 2 подмасива, один 2-ч мерный и один простой.
Дальше массив выводится под соответствующим HTML шаблоном.
Для этого мне нужно извлечь подмассивы в отдельные переменные, и я знаю 4 варианта:

1. $subArray1 = $bigArray['subArray1'];
       $subArray2 = $bigArray['subArray2'];
2. list($subArray1, $subArray2) = $bigArray;
3. $subArray2 = array_pop($bigArray);
       $subArray1 = array_pop($bigArray);
4. $subArray1 = array_shift($bigArray);
       $subArray2 = array_shift($bigArray);

Задался вопросом, какой наиболее лучший с точки зрения производительности
и нет ли альтернативного варианта доступа к каждому подмассиву большого массива по ссылке.

Comment: чето ваще непонятно) можно дамп массива и то что вы хотите из него получать?

Comment: такой сложный массив я мог бы не использовать, если бы я знал, что такой кусочек кода сработает:
function getRow()
{
   ...
   $row = mysql_query($query);
   $row['uniqueKey'] = 'some text data';
   return $row;
}

Comment: Невооруженный глаз подсказывает, что первый вариант самый производительный.

Comment: мне кажется, что в первом варианте мы удваиваем количество памяти:
большой массив остаётся, а кроме него созданы 2 новые переменные, которые вместе занимают столько же памяти, что и большой массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант, пожалуй, самый лучший в данном случае. Потребление памяти особо не увеличится, т.к. PHP реально скопирует массив только в тот момент, когда вы измените хотя бы один элемент.

`list()` - это всего лишь усложнение первого.

`array_pop()` и `array_shift()` еще и массив будут изменять.

Можете поэкспериментировать:

```
// массив
$a = array();
for ($i = 0; $i<600; $i++)
{
    $a[0][$i] = str_repeat('Первый', 50);
    $a[1][$i] = str_repeat('Второй', 50);
    for ($j = 0; $j<3; $j++)
    {
        $a[0][$i][$j] = str_repeat('йывреП', 30);
        $a[1][$i][$j] = str_repeat('йоротВ', 30);
    }
}

// и проверка
for ($i = 0; $i<100; $i++)
{
    // list(${'f'.$i}, ${'s'.$i}) = $a;

    // ${'f'.$i} =  $a[0];
    // ${'s'.$i} =  $a[1];

    // ${'f'.$i} = array_pop($a); 
    // ${'s'.$i} = array_pop($a);

    // ${'f'.$i} = array_shift($a); 
    // ${'s'.$i} = array_shift($a);

    // Эксперимент с памятью: 
    // раскомментировать первую строку, запустить -> посмотреть потребление памяти, 
    // раскомментировать вторую -> посмотреть как потребление выросло в несколько раз
    // ${'tmp'.$i} = $a;
    // ${'tmp'.$i}[0][10][5] = 'Новый';
}
```

*не было же мне чем заняться..*